# Alteração de tipos de dados em uma lista em Python

Tags: python, lista, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho uma lista `x`, com **10 números**, sendo todos eles **inteiros**. Gostaria de tornar todos eles em números do tipo `float`, mas não consigo realizar essa conversão.

Código:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


for i in acs:
    acs[i]= float(i)
```

Além dessa forma, também tentei o seguinte:

```
for i in acs:
    i = float(i)
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado neste código?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro aí é de não existir uma variável `acs` declarada com um objeto iterável atribuído a ela.

Uma dica de como resolver com menos linhas e bem legível:

Percorra todos os itens na lista transformando eles em float e guardando o novo objeto do tipo lista na variável de sua preferência.

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lista_float = [float(item) for item in lista]
```

Dá pra fazer com um `for` fora de uma `list comprehension`, que é mais fácil de entender pra quem vem de outras linguagens:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lista_float = []
for item in lista:
    lista_float.append(float(item))
```

O `.append()` que eu usei ali serve para adicionar itens numa lista já criada.

Answer (score 2):

acs ñ esta declarado

## usando append

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
acs = []

for i in lista:
    acs.append(float(i))
```

## usando map

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
acs = [*map(float, lista)]
```

## usando compreensao

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
acs = [float(x) for x in lista]
```